# AWS EIP Limit Increase

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami, elastic-ip

I understand that I get 5 EIP per region and if I need more I need to request service limit increase.

My question is how many can I get after service limit increase? Is it possible to get 50 EIP?

Please note that the DNS IP that AWS provides is not an option since that cannot be assigned to after instance is created and DNS IP cannot be attached to the second interface of my device (it can only be assigned to eth0 of a given EC2 instance)

All I need is a public IP that I can assign to eth1 or eth2
And I need to do that for about 50 EC2 instances.

Comment: yes you can get more 50 EIP. All you need to do is requesting them by specifying the description/reason for that number in form https://aws.amazon.com/support/createCase?serviceLimitIncreaseType=elastic-ips&type=service_limit_increase

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes you can get more EIP on request. You can then attach/reattach them for your EC2 instances.

Contact AWS Support - Indicating the Service Limit Increase.

- EIP Service Limit Increase - [Link](https://aws.amazon.com/support/createCase?serviceLimitIncreaseType=elastic-ips&type=service_limit_increase)
- General EC2 Limits Info - [Link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_ec2)

Answer (score 2):

you can increase your EIP service limit increase by

1. Service Quota console https://console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/home/services/ec2/quotas/L-0263D0A3
2. By AWS Support Console (Service Limit Increase)
3. By API calls like boto3 https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/service-quotas.html#ServiceQuotas.Client.request_service_quota_increase or using cli like https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/service-quotas/request-service-quota-increase.html

we can automate this process in aws

1. create cloudtrail for multiregion enable log stream
2. Using Log Group we will add Log Subscription filter where we have to define filter pattern "AllocateAddress" and add lambda function with it
3. In our lambda function we will create Python Script in which
   we will check all region total number of Elastic Ip present in all region and fetch applied quota value from Service Quota then make math expression ((current EIP value/Applied Quota Value)*100) if the
   value is grater then 80% then sent request to increase request value

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: additional thing we can setup this process automatically  in aws 1. create cloudtrail for multiregion enable log stream 2. Using Log Group we will add Log Subscription filter where we have to define filter pattern "AllocateAddress" and add lambda function with it 3. In our lambda function we will create Python Script in which we will check all region total number of Elastic Ip present in all region and fetch applied quota value from Service Quota then make math expression ((current EIP value/Applied Quota Value)*100) if the value is grater then 80% then sent request to increase request value

Answer (score 1):

There is a new process in 2023 using the AWS Quota pages (link [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html)) As per the docs:

1. Open the Service Quotas [console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/).
2. On the Dashboard, choose Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2). If Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) is not listed on the Dashboard, choose AWS services, enter EC2 in the search field, and then choose Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2).
3. On the Amazon EC2 service quotas page, enter IP in the search field.
4. The limit is EC2-VPC Elastic IPs. (If you have access to EC2-Classic, there is an additional limit, EC2-Classic Elastic IPs. For more information, choose the limit.)